# GWT: Retrieving data from Postgres in GWT CellTable

Tags: java, postgresql, gwt, gwt-rpc, postgresql-9.1

I have a LinkedList as

```
/**
   * The list of data to display.
   */
private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS = new LinkedList<Contact>(Arrays.asList(
        new Contact("Some string", "1234", "5678")));
```

and now instead of this List I want to retrieve this data from Postgres. I don't know how should I do that. An example would be great! Thank you.

Comment: I need to retrieve the data in a CellTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [RPC tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC) at Google Developers. It builds on top of their stockwatcher project and explains the basics of a client-server solution with gwt.

For your project you'll want a service that can respond with data from a database.